# UL LI to HTML menu structure with recursive function

Tags: jquery, html

I can't seem to make up my ul/li menu properly. I'm using a recursive function to generate the proper menu layout, but it seems it can't handle the submenu's.

The source:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Top menu</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Some page</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-submenu item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The 'should-be-correct' output modified by the script

```
<div class="" role="navigation" id="p-">
  <h3>Top menu</h3>
  <div class="body">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="" role="navigation" id="p-">
        <h3>Some page</h3>
        <div class="body">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
            <li>
              <div class="" role="navigation" id="p-">
                <h3>Submenu item 3</h3>
                <div class="body">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-submenu item 1</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/fb0kqxg6/2/

What is the best way to go here?

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: It wont generate the output I want, but I can't seem the find what's wrong - so whats wrong? :D

Comment: So long to debug such a complex algorithm, you should try to simplify it so it is easier to understand (for instance add comments in your code !!). You should also add logs to see why the algorithm doesn't go in the `if` you expected... It would be faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some dom manipulation like

```js
var $ul = $('#menu').clone();

$ul.find('li:has(ul)').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $a = $this.children('a').remove();
  $this.wrapInner('<div class="" role="navigation" id="p-"><div class="body"></div></div>');
  $('<h3 />', {
    text: $a.text()
  }).prependTo($this.children())

})

$ul.appendTo('#menus')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Top menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Some page</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-submenu item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="menus">
</div>
```